# Disaster exposure as treatment in survival analysis - multiple "treatments" / pre-"treatment" trends (in R)

Tags: r, survival, cox-model, proportional-hazards

I am looking at using a cox proportional hazards model to look at migration after disasters. I have two disasters at T1 and T2 (which are two years apart). I created two models looking at the risk of exposure in the 18 months following the disaster to see if disaster exposure was associated with changes to the risk of migration. Individuals exposed to the disasters were more likely to move (the model is a bit more complicated, but I think that's the important bit for the question).

Post Disaster
coxph(Surv(time1, status1) ~ disaster1 + controls, data = T1Population)
coxph(Surv(time2, status2) ~ disaster2 + controls, data = T2Population)

Where T1Population is the population in the area at T1; time1 is time to migration within 18 months of T1, and status1 is whether individuals migrated within time1. disaster1 is the treatment for exposure to the disaster.

This is repeated for disaster 2 with the 18 months after T2, and population in the area at T2 (which is similar but not identical to T1Population due to interim migration). disaster2 is the treatment for exposure to the disaster.

My advisor wanted me to see if there was an endogeneity issue where there was something about the areas where disasters are likely to hit that is associated with greater mobility with or without the disaster exposure. So, I recreated the models using T0 (two years prior to T1) to see if individuals in areas to be hit by the disasters were more likely to move than a control. This was in fact the case, but the effect isn't as strong.

Pre-Disaster Robustness Check
coxph(Surv(time0, status0) ~ disaster1 + controls, data = T0Population)
coxph(Surv(time0, status0) ~ disaster2 + controls, data = T0Population)

Where T0Population is the population in the area at T0; time0 is time to migration within 18 months of T0, and status0 is whether individuals migrated within time0. disaster1 and disaster2 in these models refers to whether individuals are in areas that will be hit by these disasters.

Now my advisor wants me to combine these into one model. Basically there would be a 5.5 year period from T0 to T2+18months, the population would be everyone who lived there at T0 or who moved into the area by T2. There would be a pre-treatment period, and two post-treatment periods. I have no idea if this works, or how to go about modeling this. Does anyone have any insight into if this makes sense, and how I would code it in R.